# Kongruenz Adjektiv–Nomen

Tags: inflection

Warum "die welk Sonnenblumen" anstatt "die welken Sonnenblumen"?

..., die die welk bis auf den Teerbelag herunterhängenden Sonnenblumen teilten.

Comment: Quelle: Antònio Lobo Antunes - Portugals strahlende Größe, [Leseprobe inkl. des Zitats](http://www.bookinist.de/bookinist/content/text/xolds/hase/@anportu.htm) oder [hier](https://www.bic-media.com/mobile/mobileWidget-jqm1.4.html?bgcolor=E9E8E8&showExtraDownloadButton=yes&isbn=9783442736287&buttonOrder=book-audio-video&https=yes&socialSelfBackLink=yes&iconType=rh5&iconTypeSecondary=rh5&lang=de&fullscreen=yes&jump2=0&flipBook=no&openFSIPN=yes&resizable=yes&buyUrl=https://www.randomhouse.de/cart/add/218058.rhd)

Comment: @FrankfromFrankfurt: »Adverb« und »Adjektiv« sind Wortarten. Zu welcher Wortart ein Wort gehört hängt aber nicht vom tatsächlichen Gebrauch ab. Auch wenn ein Wort einfach nur in einem Wörterbuch aufgelistet ist, ist es entweder ein Verb, ein Substantiv, ein Adjektiv, ein Adverb oder etwas anderes. Das Wort *»welk«* ist zum Beispiel ein Adjektiv (siehe z.B. [Wiktionary: welk](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/welk), ganz egal, wie und wo im Satz man es verwendet, während z.B. [oft](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/oft) ein Adverb ist, ebenfalls ganz unabhängig davon, wie es wo verwendet wird.

Comment: @Schölnast: Vielen Dank für die Belehrung, dass die meisten deutschen Grammatiker einem Adjektiv in adverbialem Gebrauch absprechen ein Adverb zu sein. Ich denke, dass der Hinweis, das Wort als Adverb zu interpretieren, trotzdem hilfreich war.

Answer (score 7):

Inzwischen weiss ich schon weshalb es so ist (denke ich). In diesem Fall ist es ein Adverbiales Adjektiv, daher verändert seine Form nicht.

Comment: @ Carsten S - Done.

Answer (score 0):

> anstatt "die welke Sonnenblumen"?

Das wäre völlig falsch.

---

> "die welk Sonnenblumen"

Das ist nicht in dem Satz

> > ..., die die welk bis auf den Teerbelag herunterhängenden Sonnenblumen teilten.

gesagt, und wäre auch falsch.

Frage einfach nach der Art des Herunterhängens der Sonnenblumen in diesem Fall:

> Wie hängen die Sonnenblumen herunter?
>   welk

Comment: Nein. Frag' lieber was anderes - "wie hängen die Blumen herunter?".

Comment: @tofro Fixed. ....

Comment: Du willst auch noch den Satz davor reparieren. Der sollte lauten "frage einfach nach der Art des Herunterhängens der Sonnenblumen"

Comment: @tofro Done. Danke vielmals.